# PDO execute not found error given in PHP storm

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a file named chat.php with a namespace **MyApp** and am trying to connect to database using PDO and insert some data but in my IDE I get an error saying **Method execute not found**. Where am I going wrong?

Following are some parts of the code:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Emojione\Client;
use Emojione\Ruleset;
use \PDO;
use \PDOException;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
protected $clients;
/**
 * @var \Emojione\Client
 */
private $emojioneClient;

public function __construct() {
    $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    /**
     * Following for setting up conversion and display of native and ascii emojis
     */
    $this->emojioneClient = new Client(new Ruleset());
    $this->emojioneClient->imageType = 'png';
    $this->emojioneClient->imagePathPNG = './assets/png/';
    $this->emojioneClient->ascii = true;

    $this->connect();
}
.
.
.
.
.

public function connect() {
    $hostname='localhost';
    $dbname = 'cryptoIM';
    $username='root';
    $password='';

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo 'Connected to Database<br/>';
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo ('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function insertData() {
    $query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO inbox(users, message, attachmentURI, timestamps) VALUES (:username, :messagetxt, :attachmentURI, :unixtime)");
    $query->execute(array(
        "username" => "",
        "messagetxt" => "",
        "attachmentURI" => "",
        "unixtime" => ""
    ));
}
```

Comment: Try `$this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:hos....` then use `$this->dbh` not `$dbh` !

Comment: you should be getting the error at `$dbh->prepare` since it's out of scope for the function.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII at prepare I get No data sources are configured to run this sql and provide....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `$dbh` is not available in `insertData()` scope. Try to add `$dbh` to `$this` (class scope), and you must add colons `:` to your `execute()` array keys.

```
class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;
    protected $dbh;
```

then:

```
public function connect() {
    //...    
    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

        $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo 'Connected to Database<br/>';
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo ('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

then:

```
public function insertData() {
    $query = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO inbox(users, message, attachmentURI, timestamps) VALUES (:username, :messagetxt, :attachmentURI, :unixtime)");
    $query->execute(array(
        ":username" => "", //Don't forget to add colons ':'
        ":messagetxt" => "",
        ":attachmentURI" => "",
        ":unixtime" => ""
    ));
}
```

About the error **Method execute not found.** I think you must get **Call to a member function on a non-object** or something similar !

Comment: If you could show me an example of what you mean for the last para it would be helpful cause the error isn't gone.

Comment: One additional note ! I can see that you use `MessageComponentInterface` is this interface has any methods that you should implement !!

Comment: Yes it has methods which is Implemented. I updated my code according to your answer but I still have that highlight. Will it make any significant error in future?

Comment: Try to execute the code and see what's the result !

Comment: I executed but unfortunately somehow the app is crashing and if I remove the `$this->connect();` from the constructor, the whole app works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118698/discussion-between-ayan-and-ismail-rbouh).

Answer (score 1):

since you're going to use this object throughout different functions in your class, then you need to declare it as a private class variable.

```
class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
protected $clients;
private $dbh;
```

Then initialize it in your constructor's call to `connect`.

```
try {
    $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname; dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo 'Connected to Database<br/>';
}
```

And reference the class property as such elsewhere:

```
public function insertData() {
    $query = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO inbox(users, message, attachmentURI, timestamps) VALUES (:username, :messagetxt, :attachmentURI, :unixtime)");
```